# Java: How can i persist RandomStringUUID object at runtime

Tags: java

Here is the scenario:
I have:

```
public class RandomStringUUID {

    public RandomStringUUID() {
        final String uuidstring = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
    }


    public String getRandomStringUUID() {
        final String uuidst = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
        return uuidst;
    }
}
```

Where i am generating a Unique Value.

Then in :

```
public class AddSingleDomain {

    public static RandomStringUUID RUUID = new RandomStringUUID();

    @Test
    public void addSingleDomain() {
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(DomainsPage.getTitle(), "View Account");


        String randomUIDSeed = RUUID.getRandomStringUUID();

        System.out.println("Random Domanin Name Prefix: "
                + randomUIDSeed);
        System.out.println("Random Domanin Name Prefix: " + RUUID);


        getDriver().findElement(By.name("vo.zoneName")).sendKeys(
                randomUIDSeed + ".tv");
```

I use it, and then, yet in another class:

public class VerifyDBSingleDomain {

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@a.b.c.d:1521:ms";

@Test
public void VerifyDBSingleDomainTest()  {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", "user");
    props.setProperty("password", "pass");


String sql = "Select zoneid from zone where zonename =" +  randomUIDSeed + ".tv";
```

I want to use the SAME VALUE "randomUIDSeed"
If in class VerifyDBSingleDomain i : String randomUIDSeed = RUUID.getRandomStringUUID();
would it be the same object ? How can i use this as same object, and hence guranteeing the same value across ALL classes during runtime.

Comment: Note that your method `RandomStringUUID.getRandomStringUUID()` returns a new, different string every time you call it. Is that really what you wanted?

Comment: @kamal Under what circumstances do you want the id to be the same? It's not so clear to me, sorry. Do you want it to change after the App has been quit and started again?

Comment: @Fildor
Yes, after the app has quit the randomUUID value should change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by making this little change:

```
public class RandomStringUUID {

    private static final String MYUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");

    public static String getRandomStringUUID() { return MYUUID; }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
// Anywhere in your code: vv Note that we are using the classname! The method is static.
String theCommonID = RandomStringUUID.getRandomStringUUID();
```

This is just a hint into the direction. This is not a "perfect" clean solution. You might want to google "Singleton Design Pattern". And I can imagine ~10 other ways to do this right now ... But anyway.

This will create one of your IDs **once** for the runtime of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, however;

The short answer to your question is "Yes you will get the same String instance".
The slightly longer answer is "But you're doing it wrong".

You really should use a persistence framework to help you deal with these issues.

Comment: I agree that there are a _lot_ of issues with the OP's code. But I disagree that he needs a persitence framework. First of all, he should  explain, if and when he wants the randomUUID to be the same or not.

Comment: @Fildor
I want randomUUID to be the same, i thought it was clear, but seems not